# Insert a form to a Basic Page

Tags: forms, 8

I created a contact form in Drupal 8 and would like to use that form on several pages across my website. Can I do something like Insert / Form or use some sort of shortcode to display the form?

Answer (score 1):

Create a block for your theme with [formblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) and in visibility settings of your block put it where ever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I installed Form Block, but I'm not sure where to look for the checkbox to enable add as block. The documentation says "Go to the admininstration page of the contenttype from which the 'add' form should be made available as a block.", but that's not very helpful. Where should I look for it?

Comment: @Ondrej in form settings

Comment: Understood, but where exactly are those? If I open a contact form, I see Edit, Manage fields, Manage form display, Manage display, Translate, Devel. None of these includes the checkbox.